# How to add angularJs variable to an outputLink

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

I want to add an angularJs variable `item.Id` to the link, i tried that and it does not work:

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/showResultQuiz?id={{item.Id}}">
```

it gives me that:

```
   https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/showResultQuiz?id=%7B%7Bitem.Id%7D%7D
```

it does not change the {{item.Id}} with the actual value, it just prints out the letters.

Comment: you have to give like {!item.Id}

Comment: No it's an angular Js expression not visualforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server-side `apex:outputLink` tag is (correctly) escaping characters that should not be in a valid URL because it doesn't know you are going to do some client-side processing.

So instead use the raw HTML tag equivalent:

```
<a href="https://c.cs86.visual.force.com/apex/showResultQuiz?id={{item.Id}}">...</a>
```

which is passed through to the client-side unprocessed by Visualforce.